# Excatly what to put into dependency injection conatiner? Isnt DI increases coupling?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

While I know its good to use, lest not overuse it. Example:

```
class Point
{
    private $x, $y, $graphicsEngine;

    public function __constructor($x, $y, $graphicsEngine)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
        $this->graphicsEngine = $graphicsEngine;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        $this->graphicsEngine->draw($this);
    }
}

class GraphicsEngine
{
    public function draw(Point $p)
    {
        ....
    }
}

$graphicsEngine = new GraphicsEngine();
$graphicsEngine->draw (new Point(5,2));
```

Point must know about GraphicsEngine. If I rewrite it DI form:

```
class Point
{
    private $x, $y;

    public function __constructor($x, $y)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        DI::get('graphicsEngine')->draw($this);
    }
}

class GraphicsEngine
{
    public function draw(Point $p)
    {
        ....
    }
}

DI::set('graphicsEngine', new GraphicsEngine());
DI::get('graphicsEngine'->draw (new Point(5,2));
```

this looks a bit lighter code, though the DI itself is highly coupled to the application. GraphicsEngine and Point used to be more independent, but now DI is highly coupled to the all application. They no longer cant be put into other application too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your objects should not be aware of the existence of an IoC container:

```
class Point
{
    private $x, $y;

    public function __constructor($x, $y)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        DI::get('graphicsEngine')->draw($this); // WRONG: DIRECT REFERENCE TO DI!!!
    }
}
```

I'm trying to help because I'm the author of an IoC container for JavaScript. Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with your IoC container or PHP. I will try my best to explain how to solve this issue.

```
class Point
{
    private private $x, $y, $graphicsEngine;

    public function __constructor($x, $y)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    public function draw()
    {
        // graphicsEngine is only used when draw is invoked
        // we can lazy inject graphicsEngine 
        $this->graphicsEngine->draw($this);
    }
}

class GraphicsEngine
{
    public function draw(Point $p)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

To learn how to configure lazy inject you need to refer to [lazy-injection](http://php-di.org/doc/lazy-injection.html).

Remember that **your objects should not be aware of the existence of an IoC container**. Your IoC container will be configure somewhere in your app all the IoC configuration should be centralized in one single file. This file will be full of type bindings:

```
 DI::set('X', X);
 DI::set('Y', Y);
 // ...
```

A type binding is a mapping between a key (e.g.`graphicsEngine`) and an implementation (e.g.`GraphicsEngine`). You can think of the IoC container configuration as a dictionary of type bindings.

The IoC container owns the dictionary of type bindings. This means that the IoC container is aware of all the types (Classes and Interfaces) in your application but your types are not aware of the IoC container.

The IoC container is like a "God" that sees everything and your objects are unaware of the existence of this "God" or other Classes. Your classes will not be coupled but coupling needs to take place somewhere and that somewhere is the IoC configuration.

We can say that IoC containers don't remove coupling because coupling is necessary at run-time. What IoC container help us to do is to centralize the coupling into one single point in the entire application instead of having coupling all around the place.